# can't use an array to add_option in register_activation_hook

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin and want to set default values for 2 options. This works fine until I want to use the value from an array that is outside the function using global.
I have tried with the array inside the function and it works fine that way but once the array is outside i get a NULL value for the array, here is my code:

```
    $css_vars_system= array();//default values to start with
$css_vars_system[]= array('name'=> 'secondary', 'value' => '#6c757d' , 'comment' => 'The secondary colour' , 'type' => 'system');
$css_vars_system[]= array('name'=> 'success', 'value' => '#28a745' , 'comment' => '' , 'type' => 'system');

//on activation
function tryrs_options_on_activation()
{

        global $css_vars_system;
        //set default values
        if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' ))
                {
                    //add_option('tryrs_design_options_vars', 'some updated value');
                    add_option('tryrs_design_options_header', 'header_1.php','','no');
                    add_option('tryrs_design_options_css_vars', $css_vars_system,'','no');
                }

}//end function
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'tryrs_options_on_activation');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
$GLOBALS['css_vars_system']= array();//default values to start with
$GLOBALS['css_vars_system'][]= array('name'=> 'secondary', 'value' => '#6c757d' , 'comment' => 'The secondary colour' , 'type' => 'system');
$GLOBALS['css_vars_system'][]= array('name'=> 'success', 'value' => '#28a745' , 'comment' => '' , 'type' => 'system');
```

.. *or*:

```
global $css_vars_system;
$css_vars_system= array();//default values to start with
$css_vars_system[]= array('name'=> 'secondary', 'value' => '#6c757d' , 'comment' => 'The secondary colour' , 'type' => 'system');
$css_vars_system[]= array('name'=> 'success', 'value' => '#28a745' , 'comment' => '' , 'type' => 'system');
```

.. *or* add these functions: *But this is really just a suggestion.*

```
function tryrs_design_default_options() {
    return array(
        'header'   => 'header_1.php',
        'css_vars' => array(
            array( 'name' => 'secondary', 'value' => '#6c757d', 'comment' => 'The secondary colour', 'type' => 'system' ),
            array( 'name' => 'success', 'value' => '#28a745', 'comment' => '', 'type' => 'system' ),
        ),
    );
}

function tryrs_design_default_option( $name ) {
    $options = tryrs_design_default_options();
    if ( isset( $options[ $name ] ) ) {
        return $options[ $name ];
    }
}
```

.. and then in `tryrs_options_on_activation()`:

```
add_option('tryrs_design_options_header', tryrs_design_default_option('header'),'','no');
add_option('tryrs_design_options_css_vars', tryrs_design_default_option('css_vars'),'','no');
```

Comment: Thank you Sally but this did not work for me, it is as if anything outside the activation function is ignored

Comment: That's a bit strange, because it worked for me — see [sample plugin](https://pastebin.com/u6Lyh8rx); however, I'm glad you that managed to find a workaround. Good luck!

Comment: i am sorry, I must have done something wrong when testing, I have done it again and it is working fine (second snipet), many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is a work around, I have added a separate PHP file where the $css_vars_system is located and bring it inside the function (and where ever else I need it) with a PHP include.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! =)